# How to rebuild dropdown menu with bootstrap select?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to implement `bootstrap-select` in my application. I already use Bootstrap-twitter in my application. There are few drop-down menus in the system where I would like to implement this feature. On page load bootstrap-select will be triggered and drop down menu is populated from json file. I have form int he system where JSON file can be updated. In that case I reload JSON file and call function to load the json again. The problem is that bootstrap-select breaks in that case. I still can click and search through the options but at the same time all options are showing below the select input field. Here is example of my code:

```js
var appData = {
  Buildings : [
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 1", BLDGNUMBER : "2234"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 2", BLDGNUMBER : "2534"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 3", BLDGNUMBER : "2734"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 4", BLDGNUMBER : "2294"}
  ]
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  loadBuildings();
});

function loadBuildings(){
    populateBuildings();
    /* Just to show the way I import JSON data.
    $.getJSON("JSON/Buildings.json?"+ new Date().getTime(), function(json) {
        appData.Buildings = json;
    }).done(function() {
        populateBuildings();
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown);
    });
    */
}

function populateBuildings(){
    var fldBldg = $(".bldg-menu");
    fldBldg.find("option:gt(0)").remove(); // Remove all but the first option in select menu.

    $.each(appData.Buildings, function (key, value) {
        fldBldg.append($("<option></option>").val(value.BLDGNUMBER).text(value.BLDGNAME));
    });
    fldBldg.selectpicker("refresh");
}

$("#add").on("click",addNew);
function addNew(){
  appData.Buildings.push({BLDGNAME : "Test 5", BLDGNUMBER : "6234"});
  loadBuildings();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmDemog" id="frmDemo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="bldg"><span class="label label-primary">Building:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control bldg-menu selectpicker" name="frmDemo_bldg" id="frmDemo_bldg" data-live-search="true" required>
      <option value="">--Choose Building--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add New</button>
```

If you run snippet above and click on the add button you will see all options below the select menu. I'm not sure how I can reload the `selectpicker()` to prevent that behavior. I have tried using `selectpicker("refresh")` but that did not help. If anyone knows the way to fix this please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This code selects two elements: DIV generated by Bootstrap-Select and SELECT.

```js
var fldBldg = $(".bldg-menu");
```

Change it to:

```js
var fldBldg = $("select.bldg-menu");
```

### Fixed code:

```js
var appData = {
  Buildings : [
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 1", BLDGNUMBER : "2234"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 2", BLDGNUMBER : "2534"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 3", BLDGNUMBER : "2734"},
    {BLDGNAME : "Test 4", BLDGNUMBER : "2294"}
  ]
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  loadBuildings();
});

function loadBuildings(){
    populateBuildings();
    /* Just to show the way I import JSON data.
    $.getJSON("JSON/Buildings.json?"+ new Date().getTime(), function(json) {
        appData.Buildings = json;
    }).done(function() {
        populateBuildings();
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown);
    });
    */
}

function populateBuildings(){
    var fldBldg = $("select.bldg-menu");
    fldBldg.find("option:gt(0)").remove(); // Remove all but the first option in select menu.

    $.each(appData.Buildings, function (key, value) {
        fldBldg.append($("<option></option>").val(value.BLDGNUMBER).text(value.BLDGNAME));
    });
    fldBldg.selectpicker("refresh");
}

$("#add").on("click",addNew);
function addNew(){
  appData.Buildings.push({BLDGNAME : "Test 5", BLDGNUMBER : "6234"});
  loadBuildings();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmDemog" id="frmDemo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="bldg"><span class="label label-primary">Building:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control bldg-menu selectpicker" name="frmDemo_bldg" id="frmDemo_bldg" data-live-search="true" required>
      <option value="">--Choose Building--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add New</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out selector issue. I didn't know that class is getting cloned to the div element. I'm wondering if you know how to take care of the width? Is there any good way to handle that with bootstrap-select and not to affect the form layout. I would like select menu to match the width of the field. I hope this make sense.

Comment: Replied today to the width question :) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302044/9921853)

Comment: I have looked over your link about the width issue. My problem is not the same. I found the code that caused the issue in my case. `.selectpicker("refresh");` If that code is included then one of my select menus is narrow and does not have the max height. Instead of going just to the bottom border of the browser it expands more than that. If I remove `.selectpicker("refresh");` that issue is solved. I still need to refresh the select menu after form is saved. So I'm wondering how to do that and not to break the width and height on the menu?